# Unable to add WCF reference in VS2010, but IExplorer can see ?wsdl

Tags: wcf

In my work PC the service works perfectly (and my solution) hosted in Win7's IIS on an Https address. When bringing this to home also using Win7 + IIS I had some problems calling the service. Decided to change the service to http and so I did configuring the web site in IIS, but the problems continue.

I'm able to see the metadata by calling something like this from IExplorer 9: http://develop:83/GeneralService.svc?wsdl. However VS2010 is not able to build the proxy from this. Get this error:

---

The document at the url http://localhost:83/GeneralService.svc was not recognized as a known document type.

The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:

- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
- Report from 'http://localhost:83/GeneralService.svc' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'There was an error downloading 'http://develop:83/GeneralService.svc?disco'.'.

  - Unable to connect to the remote server
  - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.192.15.2:83
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:83/GeneralService.svc'.

There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:83/GeneralService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

---

This is my service configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <ws2007HttpBinding>
      <binding name="EnlaceGeneral"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="6291456">
        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="1300" />
      </binding>
    </ws2007HttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="ComportamientoGeneral"
              name="SipodWPF.Web.Services.GeneralService">
      <endpoint address="GeneralService.svc"
                binding="ws2007HttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="EnlaceGeneral"
                name="ExtremoGeneral"
                contract="SipodWPF.Web.Services.IGeneralService" />
      <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                contract="SipodWPF.Web.Services.IGeneralService" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ComportamientoGeneral">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"
                          httpsGetEnabled="false" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                              multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false">
    <serviceActivations>
      <add relativeAddress="GeneralService.svc"
            service="SipodWPF.Web.Services.GeneralService" />
    </serviceActivations>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

---

This is one of the reasons I haven't presented hat exam yet :o)

After 5 hours I'm pretty lost. Any help wold be appreciated.

Comment: You can see the metadata by calling `http://develop:83/GeneralService.svc?wsdl`, but you get an error message saying no endpoint at `http://localhost:83/GeneralService.svc` - one uses develop:83 and other (the one failing) is localhost:83.  Could that be it?

Comment: Notice the content type you're getting back is `text/html`. That's an error message coming back from the service. You need to read that message to find out what the service is trying to tell you. Install Fiddler, then look at the faq to learn how to capture local traffic.

Comment: Thanks for your help. well.. really don't know how to solve the address issue. I've change it to http://localhost:83/GeneralService.svc, http://develop:83/GeneralService.svc or just GeneralService.svc and still get the same result.

Comment: So, if you browse using IE to http://localhost:83/GeneralService.svc instead of http://develop:83/GeneralService.svc?wsdl on your personal PC, does that work?

Comment: Sorry for being this late, I was out of town. Actually your two addresses work in IE, is VS2010 my problem.

Comment: Thank you everyone who helped me. I solved this reinstalling VS2010.